# Parsing Nested JSON and Display it in a Specific Format

Tags: javascript, html, json, user-interface

I am writing a commenting system. For a particular page, I am fetching the the comments as highly nested JSONs (a comment contains its children, that in turn may contain other children). I want to parse and display these comments in a threaded manner. Here's an example of one such JSON:

```
{
  "children": [
    {
      "children": [
        {
          "children": [],
          "content": "Here is a child8",
          "id": "child8",
          "pageURIHash": "3988665684",
          "parentId": null
        }
      ],
      "content": "Here is child1",
      "id": "child1",
      "pageURIHash": "3988665684",
      "parentId": null
    },
    {
      "children": [
        {
          "children": [],
          "content": "Here is child3",
          "id": "child3",
          "pageURIHash": "3988665684",
          "parentId": null
        },
        {
          "children": [],
          "content": "Here is child4",
          "id": "child4",
          "pageURIHash": "3988665684",
          "parentId": null
        },
        {
          "children": [],
          "content": "Here is a child5",
          "id": "child5",
          "pageURIHash": "3988665684",
          "parentId": null
        },
        {
          "children": [
            {
              "children": [
                {
                  "children": [],
                  "content": "Here is a child9",
                  "id": "child9",
                  "pageURIHash": "3988665684",
                  "parentId": null
                },
                {
                  "children": [],
                  "content": "Here is a child10",
                  "id": "child10",
                  "pageURIHash": "3988665684",
                  "parentId": null
                }
              ],
              "content": "Here is a child7",
              "id": "child7",
              "pageURIHash": "3988665684",
              "parentId": null
            }
          ],
          "content": "Here is a child6",
          "id": "child6",
          "pageURIHash": "3988665684",
          "parentId": null
        }
      ],
      "content": "Here is child2",
      "id": "child2",
      "pageURIHash": "3988665684",
      "parentId": null
    }
  ],
  "content": "Here is a parent comment",
  "id": "parent",
  "pageURIHash": "3988665684",
  "parentId": null
}
```

Edit: Ignore the `null` parentIds. This is just a mock document. Each child comment will have a corresponding `parentId`, except for the top-level comment

What would be the strategy to solve this problem? I can parse the JSON but how would I display the comments in a threaded fashion? Sorry if this question appears naive but I haven't worked on the front-end much.

Thanks a lot!

Edit: I am using JQuery and Bootstrap. Here's an example of how I want the formatting to be:

https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/a9jcxo/what_are_some_nonobvious_early_signs_that_a/

Edit: Looks like I found a solution. I am using jsTree and it seems to work fine for my use-case.

Comment: Which part(key) is comment here ? What is your desired output format ? Will array of comments work for you ?

Comment: id: parent is the root comment. It has two children: child1 and child2. The output formatting that I want is like: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/a9jcxo/what_are_some_nonobvious_early_signs_that_a/

I need to show the relationship b/w parent and children comments in the UI, just like Reddit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Your question is a bit vague. Can you provide a sample of what you expect the output to be from the document you have shown in the question?</strike>

**Edit:**
From what I could understand, this document is the data structure that you use to store the "comments" on a webpage. The `content` in the document is the comment and you wish to show these in a tree like structure.

I would try recursion to flatten out the data with information like which level it is in and then use that to show the comments on the page.

eg.

```
let flattenedData = []; 

function flattenify(doc, level) {
  if (!level) {
    level = 0;
  }
  if (!doc || !doc.children || doc.children.length === 0) {
    return;
  }

  for (let index = 0; index < doc.children.length; index++) {
    let node = doc.children[index];
    flattenedData.push({
      content: node.content,
      id: node.id,
      pageURIHash: node.pageURIHash,
      parentId: node.parentId,
      level: level,
    });

    flattenify(node, (level + 1));
  }
}

flattenify(commentDoc); // the document that contains the json structure

console.log(flattenedData);
```

I have not run this code, so I do not guarantee that this will run successfully on your document. But, this should give you an idea about how to walk over it.
Use the `level` information to push spaces for indentations before the comment.

Comment: Take Reddit for example. When we load a Reddit page, it loads all the comments and displays them as threaded comments, right? The exact same way. For example: https://www.reddit.com/r/Sneakers/comments/8bbc45/alphabounce_or_ultraboost/

Comment: Here's another example containing nested comments: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/a9jcxo/what_are_some_nonobvious_early_signs_that_a/

Answer (score 0):

provide the frontend technology you are using. Is it angular, react, jQuery or something else? You might also want to specify more context if you need a more targeted answer.

**EDIT**

Since you are using JQuery, you could possibly use accordions and modify it to show the threads within each comment. Refer [Accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/) in the JQuery documentation.

Comment: I am using Bootstrap and JQuery.

Comment: Here is an example of how I want the formatting to be: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/a9jcxo/what_are_some_nonobvious_early_signs_that_a/

Comment: This is not an answer and the question is framework agnostic

Comment: I couldn't post a comment, hence the answer with a question.